# How do you select a random element out of list, in django template?

Tags: html, css, django, list, templates

I have a list of links generated in my views, now i want to redirect my page to a random link in this list. Is there a way to select a random element out of the list in the django template? I don't want to redirect the view to another view where the generation happens then redirection etc because every press of the button will lead to generation...instead simply selecting a random element out of the list so it's very fast.. Couldn't hack it via google

**template**

```
<div class="container-fluid center">

        <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light" href={{ random_link }}>Redirect me to a cute pic
        <i class="large material-icons left">favorite</i>
        <i class="large material-icons right">favorite_border</i>
        </a>

</div>
```

**views.py**

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='L685-1uBBrLbKQ', client_secret='_Fk5nW1L2h3VRR6BVnkusMh43QQ_gg',
                         user_agent='Shivam Anand')

    top_natureismetal = reddit.subreddit('natureismetal').top(limit=100)

    # generator only generated once for loop run

    nature_links = []

    for post in top_natureismetal:
        nature_links.append(post.url)

    import random

    random_link = random.choice(nature_links) #the part i want html to do...
```

Comment: If you pass a list to the template then you could use the "random" template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#random

Comment: What is the reason to NOT do the random choice in the view? Because using random template tag would have the same result from user point of view: there will be a (at rendering time randomly generated) link in the html.

Comment: The only reason I can see to not send a single link to the html is if the random link generation should be redone during user interaction with your page and the redirect happens only once when the user is "happy" with the presented random choice and hits the button. But this is then client side programming with js.  Maybe I misunderstand your point.

Comment: @Lemon.py thanks a bunch, that worked! curious: is there a way to change the link every time the button is pressed? instead of having to load the webpage again.

Comment: @Razenstein thanks for your comment! i was thinking: once the webpage is loaded there should be no time lag in clicking the button link which i thought would be the case if there is another views layer which calculates the random link after the button is pressed, although that might take care of the randomizing link with every press of the button instead of refreshing the page ..

Comment: @Razenstein some progress, constructed the list in the home page...then passed that using request.session to the view post button clicking for just the randomizing process. bit faster! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374155/how-do-i-pass-a-list-from-one-view-to-another-in-django